# Is there any way to prevent users from seing private pictures using the absolute path?

Tags: php, mysql

Imagine this situation

1. User uploads picture for everyone to see (picture is public)
2. User decides to make picture private
3. Picture is only visible to him, since the picture is set as private on the DB.

There is a problem with this:

The other users can still access the picture from its absolute path.
Is there any way to prevent this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store images outside the web root, and have a PHP script that determines if the current user has permission to access it, returning the image contents if so or a 403 Forbidden error if not.

---

You can make the file *look* like you're serving the original image:

> http://example.com/images/SunnyTrees.jpg

Use this `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule images/(.*) image.php?file=$1 [L]
```

Then your `image.php` can be:

```
<?php
$file = $_GET['file'];
// use $file to look up file information, eg. in the database
if( $it_exists && $has_permission_to_view) {
    readfile("/root/path/to/real/images/".$file);
    exit;
}
else header("HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden");
```

Comment: you won't be able to run a php script, absolute image paths contain the image extension (.jpg,png) not .php 
http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1e/Stonehenge.jpg

Comment: Use `.htaccess` rules to rewrite a request for an image to `image.php?file=$1`, with `image.php` being a file that does the processing.

Comment: a sample script for this would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can store the image in a absolute path with a complex folder name generated by "uniqid" function, but show it to the users as a streaming. With a PHP script you read the image data from the absolute path and pass it to the browser as a stream of data. If you do that since the beginning noone will ever know the absolute path. Then when the user make the image private, you check with the PHP script who has the permission to view the image, if the check is true stream the data to the user, if not, do nothing or stream a "no image" gif.

I did that already years ago but in this moment I can't find the functions that I used. But it was not complex.

See for example something like this:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php